# Is there a way to bind a wireless network to a proxy setting?

Tags: windows, linux, wireless-networking, proxy

Is there an existing program to set an specific wireless network to a certain fixed proxy configuration?

If there isn't, do you know if the necessary API exists to change it with a script or small application?

This would be usefull both on windows and linux.

Answer (score 1):

[Multi Network Manager](http://www.globesoft.com/mnm8_home.asp)

I haven't used this application since my Windows XP days but it allows a huge amount of different configurations for networking. Might suite your needs. It allows the creation of multiple different network configurations etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not automatic, OS X Leopard supports Locations which are profiles containing specific network settings (such as IP address, wifi access points and proxies). You have to manually change it when you connect to a different network, but it is not that hard. I have been using this for a while now with taking my Macbook to school and connecting to their wifi.

Windows does not seem to have a similar feature built in, but I have seen people take advantage of Firefox's Profiles to achieve a similar function. They create a new profile for each different proxy they connect to so they do not need to manually change it each time they change networks.